# Como posso compartilhar uma Imagem por Mail, Bluetooth, etc?

Tags: java, android, mobile, imagem, intent

Possuo uma `ImageView` que possui um drawable que foi editado durante o uso do app, queria pegar essa versão final da edição e enviá-la por E-mail, Bluetooth, etc..

Da forma que estou fazendo, quando envio por e-mail por exemplo, recebo uma informação que o tamanho da imagem é 0 bytes, ou seja, não consigo realizar envios..

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
  drawingView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap bitmapp = drawingView.getDrawingCache();
  resultView.setImageBitmap(bitmapp); //Aqui está a imagem que quero enviar
  Bitmap bitmap = bitmapp;
  bitmap = scaleDownBitmap(drawableToBitmap(resultView.getDrawable()), 100, resultView.getContext());// estou trabalhando com o bitmap da resultView

  Bundle param = new Bundle();
  param.putParcelable("BITMAP", bitmap);

  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setType("image/png");
  share.putExtras(param); //Estou add ele em uma Intent
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(saveImage().getAbsolutePath())); 

  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Metodo saveImage:

```
public File saveImage() {

    int imageNum = 0;
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"DCIM", "@string/app_name");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    String fileName = "imageKL_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg"; //ALTERAR PARA PNG ! ! !
    File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    while (output.exists()){
        imageNum++;
        fileName = "imageKL_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg"; //ALTERAR PARA PNG ! ! !
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    }
    try {
        drawingView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmapp = drawingView.getDrawingCache();
        resultView.setImageBitmap(bitmapp);
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapp;

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(output);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(EditImage.this, new String[]{output.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Agradeço a atenção e caso alguém saiba ou tenha alguma ideia de como resolver este problema, toda dica é bem vinda!

Comment: Olá, inclui agora o método na pergunta. Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, dei uma olhada neste site, e achei uma forma bem legal de fazer. :D
De qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção e ajuda!

Site: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Código:

```
        final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        //final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");
        final File photoFile = saveImage(); //Substitui a linha de cima por esta. . .
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share image using"));//"Share image using"
```

O método saveImage() aparece na pergunta :)

Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está invocando o `setDrawingCacheEnabled()` mas não está construindo sua imagem em cache. Tente algo parecido:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
imageView.layout(0, 0, imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela dica, estou tentando aqui, caso consiga ou não avisarei em breve. Abraço!